# Placing image buttons over a background image

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a new project that requires me to create a webform with c# that contains a background image of a map and I have to make hotspots in specific cities. Clicking on a spot I need to open a pop-up messagebox with some info.
I am thinking on putting image buttons above the background image in specific positions.

Is there a way to do that? The design mode of webforms does not help in putting images in specific places.

Comment: Please post any code that you have tried.  I would also recommend adding the 'CSS' tag as this could probably be accomplished with classes and styling.  Add specific classes to each button, and then you can target the ````background-image```` attribute.

Comment: Of course it will happen with ccs. The problem is how to find the exact settings for the place of the images without doing it manually. I have more than 500 images that I have to place in the background. Is there a tool that I can use to find the position css settings?

Comment: Still no code.... without any it's just speculation.  "Of course it will happen with CSS" -- without minimal reproducible code, what else do you expect?  Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You should try Stack Exchange (https://stackexchange.com/), as you've missed the point of Stack Overflow (reviewing CODE to solve problems).

Answer (score 0):

you can use Image map as bellow

```
<img src="workplace.jpg" alt="Workplace" usemap="#workmap">

<map name="workmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="34,44,270,350" alt="Computer" href="computer.htm">
  <area shape="rect" coords="290,172,333,250" alt="Phone" href="phone.htm">
  <area shape="circle" coords="337,300,44" alt="Coffee" href="coffee.htm">
</map>
```

Ref= https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images_imagemap.asp

Comment: That is not what I need. I need specific image buttons that I will create in specific spots above the background image.

Comment: i need to put images of people in specific spots, the color of the people will change based on a condition from code (so I need 2 images for one) and all of these will go above the background image.